# How to test headers request on a nest.js application with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to test a nest application with jest. I have a guard that calls a service, on this service I have to check if a determinate header exists, but I can't find any documentation on how I can accomplish this. Basically I'm trying to test the canActivate method from nest.js

This is my auth guard from nest.js

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return this.authService.isValidRequest(request);
  }
}
```

I want to test the method below with jest, don't know if I need to mock a Request. If the header was declared then the method will return true otherwise false.

I don't know how can test the headers in a unit test.

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor() { }

  async isValidRequest(req: Request): Promise<boolean> {
 
    const userId = req.headers['user-id'];


    if (userId != 'undefined') {
     
       // I'm going to call another service here
       return true;
      
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd honestly suggest unit testing the `AuthGuardService` over testing the `AuthGuard`, just cause the `ExecutionContext` is a bit of a beast of an object. For a super simple use case you can do

```js
describe('AuthGuardService', () => {
  let service: AuthGuardService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuardService,
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceMock}
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = modRef.get(AuthGuardService);
  });

  describe('isValidRequest', () => {
    it('should return true', async () => {
      expect(
        await service.isValidRequest({
          headers: {'user-id': 'some value that is right'}
        } as any
      )).toBe(true);
    });
    it('should return false', async () => {
      expect(
        await service.isValidRequest({
          headers: {'user-id': 'some value that is wrong'}
        } as any
      )).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

The `as any` is to keep typescript from complaining. All you care about here is that there is a `headers` proeprty